What would be the proper permissions so that perl, when called from an outside browser, can write and files to subdirectories in Ubuntu?
I have a perl script that writes a file received from a browser in the outside world to my directories on my Ubuntu server. So far I can only make it work when setting the permissions to 777, which I realize is a big no no.
My settings are as follows:

Username: daniel

Settings from Apache's envvars file are:
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data


My directory structure is:
/var/www/mydomain/public_html


But my scripts are in:
/var/www/cgi-bin


And the perl scripts write to:
/var/www/mydomain/htdocs/uploads


The permissions for htdocs and uploads are currently set to 777

The owner - group are set to daniel and www-data for both htdocs and uploads


It all works great but I cannot figure out the minimal settings so that perl, called from a web browser, can create files in /var/www/mydomain/htdocs/upload.

Unless I'm missing something or your CGI script needs to list the contents of /var/www/mydomain/htdocs/upload (for some reason), all you need should be write and execute permissions to /var/www/mydomain/htdocs/upload for www-data, can you get away with something like 730 (assuming you want daniel to have full permissions on /var/www/mydomain/htdocs/upload)?

@kos I should have added that I'm not just writing to a directory, but creating a file as well.  Because right now, neither 760 nor 770 work. If I don't make it 777, I can't seem to get it to work.

Well I can't explain it then. Another usual pitfall is some directory in the path not being traversable by the user who needs to write to the file, but if you're toggling only the permissions on the final node (upload - is this the case? Have I understood correctly?) then that can't be the problem. I want to question that the CGI script is actually running as www-data at this point. Can you leave the directory's permission to 777, edit the CGI script so that it just runs system('whoami') (writing to the target file in upload) and check that it actually shows www-data in the output?

@kos So I moved the hotdocs/upload directory to reside off of the root. Made sure they were owned by dainel and part of the group www-data.  Good idea on the whom command, it confirms that off of the browser the CGI script is running as www-data.  I was able to get it work on chmod 770, which is sort of an improvement

Well I'm glad you figured it out, although what you did doesn't explain why it wouldn't work before, if it now works with 770 it should've worked before with 770 as well, as nothing really changed (are you sure the group was set correctly before moving the folder?), however you should be able to lower them to 730 as I said initially (unless the script needs to list the contents of upload), but you certainly can't go lower than that, w+x is always required to create files. 770 by the way is fine as long as you manage groups correctly, there's nothing inherently wrong with that.

You didn't mention what's user daniel relation with the files and directories. If the user don't have to access the files, you can always change the owner of the folders to www-data.

Make www-data the owner of uploads and all the files already there:
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/mydomain/htdocs/uploads


Make all files in uploads only readable and writable by their owner (now www-data)
sudo chmod -R 600 /var/www/mydomain/htdocs/uploads


Make uploads executable. Read more on Why must a folder be executable?
sudo chmod 700 /var/www/mydomain/htdocs/uploads


Make sure htdocs is executable by the www-data user if the folder is owned by daniel (or you can change it's owner too):
sudo chmod 755 /var/www/mydomain/htdocs/



